# PHP Undefined index: HTTP_ACCEPT

Tags: php

My mobile version of website is not working. I am getting this PHP error:

```
Undefined index: HTTP_ACCEPT in /home/domain/public_html/domain.com/Mobile_Detect.php on line 97
```

And this the code from error

```
$this->accept = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'];
```

I already tried solutions from other posts or other sites... For example i tried replacing the code with this code:

```
$this->accept = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] : null;
```

Any idea?

(I am running PHP 5.6)

Comment: the last code does not work?

Comment: Last one should work fine without throwing this error. If it doesn’t, then you need to give us a _proper_ problem description - see [ask] and [mcve], please.

Comment: maybe it contains a blank string or something instead of NULL, which isset() would not pick up. But i'm surprised. I'd expect that to work.

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: so check what is actually contained in the variable, then. Use var_dump() for instance to verify

Comment: @ADyson _“maybe it contains a blank string or something instead of NULL, which isset() would not pick up.”_ - it would, I think you’re confusing it with `empty` here.

Comment: The mobile page still doesnt work. There is just blank page, and this the only error i am getting with mobile detection plugin

Comment: @CBroe http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php says "Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL... Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL. FALSE otherwise.". i.e. if the field exists but contains an empty string, isset() would return true. Although in that case, the reported error would not occur...so... ok I'm confused

Comment: @ADyson ah, forgot about the NULL part. But since $_SERVER is provided by PHP itself, I don’t think there’s ever going to be NULL values in there, at least not originally (that something would overwrite or add an index with a NULL value is possible of course) - entries are either set or not. If a value for a specific “key”/property can’t be determined from the environment, I think it doesn’t get set at all in the first place.

Comment: _“and this the only error i am getting with mobile detection plugin”_ - maybe your detection plugin manipulates the content of $_SERVER itself - we don’t know what that plugin is, so we can’t possibly know what it might do. Can you show the result of `var_dump($_SERVER);`?

Comment: var_dump is not defined

Comment: Huh, what are you talking about now? That is a basic PHP function. (At most it could have been deliberately disabled by your hoster, but then you should get an error message specifically saying that.) You need to step up your game - your problem description here still sucks, you have not provided enough info to make your problem reproducible - so go _read_ the links I posted, please, and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`Accept` is part of http headers sended by client (eg. browser, crawler...). The client could not send all headers, then you must check if **is set**:

```
$this->accept = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] : null;
```

Comment: Yeah, but they said they tried that _exact_ line already, and still got the error …

Comment: Maybe has opcache enabled without the option for recompile bytecode after PHP file change.. then, execute old code.

Comment: No i dont have opcache enabled